effective descent of coherent sheaves
I am new to stacks and algebraic spaces. I have the following question:

Let $X$ be a scheme and $G$ be a group scheme action on $X$. Then $X/G$ exists as an algebraic space. Let $\pi: X \to X/G$ be the natural map. Then by pullback and pushforward by $\pi$ we have $$Qcoh(X/G) = Qcoh(X)^G.$$
Do we have such an equality for coherent sheaves? If not then do we have the equality when we assume $G$ is finite or reductive or any other relevant properties?

In particular suppose action of $G$ on $X$ is free and  $\pi$ is flat then any $G$-equivariant coherent sheaf descends to a coherent sheaf on $X/G$. My question is when is this descent effective?


Thanks in advance.

The answer depends on the action:
If you take an action which is free, then the morphism $\pi$ is étale and, by Etale descent (cf. Bosch-Lutkebohmer-Raynaud "Neron Models page. 139) and you have equality.
But:
Take the action of $\mu_2$ over the affine line which sends $x$ in $-x$. In this case,
the morphism $\pi:{\mathbb A}^1\to {\mathbb A}^1$ is the morphism $x\mapsto x^2$.
In this case, you can see that the line bundle $(x)$ (ideal sheaf of the origin) is $\mu_2$-invariant but it is not pull back of a line bundle (its square is).

Sorry. I was implicitly supposing that $G* is finite.

Thank you for your answer. Does the freeness of the action is optimal situation where we have equality?

Freeness ensures that $X\times_{X/G} X \simeq G\times X$, so that descent data for $X\to X/G$ correspond to $G$-equivariant structures. Then flatness of $X\to X/G$ gives you effective descent. If the action is not free, you can take the quotient stack $[X/G]$ and then the equivalence in question is (basically) a tautology.
